# How create a choice parameter with list of filename get from git

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to create in a Jenkins job a choice parameter with the names of file get from a git repository but I did'nt succeed. I used extensible choice plugin and create a groovy script but it didn't work. So, I am utterly unable to proceed forward. So I wonder if it is possible and if someone else can help me to find a solution.

Regards,

Nabil

PS : Sorry if I have made mistakes, English is note my nat_ive langage

Comment: Are you really using [tag:jenkins-pipeline]? Use the [input](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#input-wait-for-interactive-input) step there. You can fill its options with computed values.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and yes I use a jenkins-pipeline but I wanted to use this list of choice before the run of the pipeline. I will try this thank you !

Comment: You can't influence the parameters of the current pipeline run. You can only update the job config, which will then be effective at the next run.

Comment: Ok, finally I chose to use the input step, thanks for all of your answers !